# After finding the object type, can I use static_cast to cast the object?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast, static-cast

I have written a function that determines which class object is passed, using **dynamic_cast**ing.
Inside the condition, can I use **static_cast** to actually cast the object?

For example, inside someFunc()

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { cout << "Base::Base" << endl; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "Base::~Base" << endl; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    void func1() { cout << "Derived1::func1()" << endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void func2() { cout << "Derived2::func2()" << endl; }
};

void someFunc(Base * bp)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(bp))
    {
        Derived1 * d1 = static_cast<Derived1 *>(bp); // static_cast ok?
        d1->func1();
    }
    else if(dynamic_cast<Derived2 *>(bp))
    {
        Derived2 * d2 = static_cast<Derived2 *>(bp); // static_cast ok?
        d2->func2();
    }
    else
        cout << "None" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Derived1 * derived1 = new Derived1;
    Derived2 * derived2 = new Derived2;
    vector<Base *> vb;
    vb.push_back(derived1);
    vb.push_back(derived2);

    // ---- Passing to someFunc() ----
    someFunc(vb.at(0));
    someFunc(vb.at(1));
}
```

Comment: You may look [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* OK, but there are some cases (involving multiple inheritance and virtual bases) where you can dynamic cast, but not static cast.

However, that is all irrelevant.  There is a much simpler way of doing what you want, just declare and initialize the variable in the `if`:

```
void someFunc(Base * bp)
{
    if(const auto d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(bp))
    {
        d1->func1();
    }
    else if(const auto d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2 *>(bp))
    {
        d2->func2();
    }
    else
        cout << "None" << endl;
}
```

Note:  `d1` and `d2` are constant pointers to mutable objects.  Given we never modify them, I like to promise the compiler that we never modify them.  That way the compiler can more easily reason about them for optimization, and I can more easily reason about them when I come to read the code in three months time.

Comment: we shoot almost equally fast :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 : `const` will indeed give constant pointers to mutable objects.  If you wanted constant objects, one would have to add the `const` to the `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `static_cast` is ok.  On the other hand, C++11 lets you write

```
if(auto d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(bp)) {
  d1-> func1();
} ...
```

so there is no need to have both.

Another option is to work with a C++17 `std::variant` (or the equivalent which is in Boost already) and avoid the if-elseif-elseif cascade, like they show on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
std::variant<Derived1*, Derived2*> p = new Derived1();
...
std::visit(overloaded(
  [](Derived1* p) { p->func1(); },
  [](Derived2* p) { p->func2(); }
), p);
```

If you can't use the common interface, this is the best option.  Note, however, that if certain code is 'type-checking' like this to call a different function on the object, you may have missed something in your design.

Comment: Actually, a declaration in the `if` statement was introduced in C++11 rather than C++14.  (Of course, the OP might still be stuck on C++03 :-( )

Comment: And it goes without saying that this is bad practice, just like using result of regular assignment in condition...

Comment: @VTT: I agree with regular assignment - this is, however, declaring a variable in a condition.  Do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: @xtofl I think this has been discussed for a very long time, ever since declaring variables inside of `for(;;)` became available breaking (or "extending" as some other people insist) existing scoping rules.

Comment: @VTT If the badness of the practice, even if held by a majority as such, doesn't induce some great chance of bugs (such as when used with parentheses), then it should probably be considered an opinion

Comment: :) In that case, I regard _your_ opinion as ... opinionated.

Comment: @xtofl You are free to say that my opinion even goes against [recommended "best practice"](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-cond).

Comment: @VTT "existing scoping rules" do you mean "all scopes begin with `{` and end with `}`"? rather than "A statement which contains sub-statements introduces a new scope" (which covers `for(;;)` et.al.)

Comment: @Caleth: That's not how it works. `static_cast` can adjust the pointer too, so it does work for `Derived3` too.

Comment: @Caleth I mean syntax originally used in C that prohibits declarations inside of parentheses in all situations. It is really surprising to see more and more fancy rules added considering how messy language syntax already is (and as a consequence, how poor language tooling is).

Answer (score 1):

You can use static_cast to cast here but you could also leverage the dynamic_cast result to do the same thing.

```
void someFunc(Base * bp)
{
    if( Derived1 * d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(bp)) 
    {
        d1->func1();
    }
    else if(Derived2 * d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2 *>(bp))
    {
        d2->func2();
    }
    else
        cout << "None" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exact duplicate of previous answer but more verbose and not const-correct.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you might use visitor pattern:

```
class Base;
class Derived1;
class Derived2;

class IBaseVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~IBaseVisitor() = default;
    virtual void visit(Base&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Derived1&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Derived2&) = 0;
};
```

Then your classes with the `accept` method:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { std::cout << "Base::Base" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Base::~Base" << std::endl; }
    virtual void accept(IBaseVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    void func1() { std::cout << "Derived1::func1()" << std::endl; }
    void accept(IBaseVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void func2() { std::cout << "Derived2::func2()" << std::endl; }
    void accept(IBaseVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
};
```

Then the usage:

```
struct SomeFuncVisitor : IBaseVisitor
{
    void visit(Base&) override { std::cout << "None" << std::endl; }
    void visit(Derived1& d1) override { d1.func1(); }
    void visit(Derived2& d2) override { d2.func2(); }
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 derived1;
    Derived2 derived2;
    std::vector<Base *> vb {&derived1, &derived2};

    SomeFuncVisitor visitor;
    for (Base* base : vb) {
        base->accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/1BezgT)